# Are there easy ways of increasing boost::multi_array dimension dynamically?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

[MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) in boost has a lot of advantages compared to creating multi-array with std::vector. However, one thing I feel uncomfortable with MultiArray in BOOST is that it is not easy to create a multi-array that can change its size easily. I have the following codes to make my point clear:

```
vector<vector<int> > my_2d_array;
vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(3);
temp.push_back(4);
my_2d_array.push_back(temp);
temp.clear;
temp.push_back(4);
temp.push_back(5);
my_2d_array.push_back(temp);
temp.clear;
temp.push_back(41);
temp.push_back(51);
my_2d_array.push_back(temp);
```

As we can see from the above codes, using `vector<vector<int> >` data structure, we can increase the dimension of the multi-array very easily. But with boost::multi_array, you have to use `boost::extents` to determine the dimension of the multi-array before using it. I was wondering whether boost::multi_array also has a easy way of increasing its dimension as the `vector<vector<int> >` did in the above codes.

Comment: I think the name is `reshaping` and yes, IIRC it has it

Comment: The big difference is `boost::multi_array` is one contiguous block of memory while with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` only the inner vectors are contiguous. There is a tradeoff between the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray.reshape(extents[newSizeY][newSizeX]);
```

works. Incidentally you can't do something like

```
boost::multi_array<int,2> foo;
// Reshape first before the following call
foo = some_function_that_returns_multi_array()
```

which has caught me out a few times. You have to reshape

The advantage with using multi_array is that the data is stored in one contiguous block, which lends itself to better cache locality, but in "real-world" tests I've noticed that you can still reap significant performance improvements using simple std::array<> on occasion, but YMMV